# Physical difference between two different attenuation coefficient functions

Tags: waves, acoustics

The attenuation of a wave through a medium can be modeled by the [Beer-Lambert Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law) using an [attenuation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuation_coefficient).  If $I$ is the intensity, and $I_r$ is a reference intensity, then what is the physical difference between modelling attenuation using the two functions below?

I am looking for a conceptual understanding of the difference between $I_1$ and $I_2$.  What does the integral in $\beta_1(\tau,\omega)$ imply?

In the equations below, $\tau$ is the time, $\omega$ is angular frequency, and $Q(\tau)$ is a real-valued function of time $\tau$.

I have seen both $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ functions used in the context of the attenuation of seismic waves through *layered media*, and I am wondering if one model is perhaps better than the other.

${I_1} = {I_r}{\beta _1}(\tau ,\omega )$

${I_2} = {I_r}{\beta _2}(\tau ,\omega )$

${\beta _1}(\tau ,\omega ) = \exp \left[- {\int\limits_0^\tau  {\frac{\omega }{{2Q(\tau ')}}d\tau '} } \right]$

${\beta _2}(\tau ,\omega ) = \exp \left[- {\frac{{\omega \tau }}{{2Q(\tau )}}} \right]$

A reference for these two equations is Y. Wang, Seismic Inverse Q Filtering ([link](http://www.scribd.com/doc/45448335/SEISMIC-INVERSE-q-FILTERING#page=132)). See for example, pg. 121.

Comment: It seems to me that $\beta_2$ is simply $\beta_1$ with the assumption that $Q(\tau)$ is approximately constant over the range $[0,\tau]$. Whether one is better than the other, I can't say.

Could you give some references for your expressions for the $\beta$s? Neither the Wikipedia page on the [Beer–Lambert Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law) nor the [attentuation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuation_coefficient) mention that integral.

Comment: @Flavin: Thanks Flavin; I think you are right.  I've now included a reference in the main body of my post.